# Trim off everything after 3rd 'p' tag in a string?

Tags: php, strpos

I have the following code:

```
$start = strpos($text, '<p>'); // Locate the first paragraph tag
$end = strpos($text, '</p>', $start); // Locate the first paragraph closing tag
$text = substr($text, $start, $end-$start+4); // Trim off everything after the closing paragraph tag
```

How to modify the above code to trim off everything after **3rd** `p` tag?

```
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
<p>this and next should be removed...</p>
```

Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This example explodes the string of text based on the `<p>` tag, then for the first 3 elements, puts it back together:

```
<?php

$text = "<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
<p>this and next should be removed...</p>";

$parts = explode ("<p>", $text);



$fin = "";
for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $fin .= "<p>" . $parts[$i];
}

echo $fin;
?>
```

Returns:

```
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```